# у меня не действует метод toLowerCase

Tags: javascript

*у меня не действует метод toLowerCase*

```
var guess = (prompt("Введите любую букву или нажмите Отмена для выхода из игры")).toLowerCase;
```

весь код:

```
var userName = prompt("Ваше имя: ");
alert("Привет ," + userName);
alert("Это игра \"Случайное слово\"");
var words = [
    "тетрадь",
    "отель",
    "спорт",
    "телефон",
    "деревня",
    "корова",
    "макака",
    "лучший",
    "игра",
    "программа",
    "природа",
    "театр",
    "город",
    "автомобиль",
    "гора",
    "карась",
    "худший",
];
var randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)];
var answerArray = [];
var remainingLetters = randomWord.length;
for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = "_";
}
while (remainingLetters > 0) {
    alert(answerArray.join(" "));
    var guess = (prompt("Введите любую букву или нажмите Отмена для выхода из игры")).toLowerCase;
    if (guess === null) {
        break;
    } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
            alert("Пожалуйста введите только одну букву!");
        } else {
            for (var j = 0; j < randomWord.length; j++) {
                if (randomWord[j] == guess) {
                    if (answerArray[j] == "_") {
                        remainingLetters--;
                        }
                    answerArray[j] = guess;


                }
                }
        } 
        }

if (remainingLetters === 0) {
alert(answerArray.join(' '));
alert("Поздравляю, вы выиграли! Было загадано слово \"" + randomWord + "\"");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var guess = (prompt("Введите любую букву или нажмите Отмена для выхода из игры")).toLowerCase`

В данном случае в переменную `guess` сохраняется ссылка на функцию, а не результат ее выполнения.

Для того, чтобы выполнить функцию необходимо добавить скобки `()` и, если необходимо, параметры

`var guess = (prompt("Введите любую букву или нажмите Отмена для выхода из игры")).toLowerCase()`

Кроме того, `prompt` может вернуть `null` и в этом случае будет исключение.